# Use 'navigation' and 'route' inside header present in class - React-navigation v5

Tags: class, routes, header, navigation, react-navigation

I'm stuck as I want to switch to the V5 version of react-navigation.
With v4, I used to pass my params and use them with :

- Set :

`this.props.navigation.navigate('MyDestination', {myParam: 'value'})`

- Get :

`this.props.navigation.getParam('myParam')`

With v5, some things changed and I now can't use the `this.props.navigation` since it's not seemed to be known by the app.

My code is splitted so I have my App.js that only refer to the Navigation class :

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import Navigation from './navigation/Navigation'

export default function App() {
  return (
      <Navigation/>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Then my Navigation file contains all the navigation mechanism (I did not added my TabBar yet, since I want to fix the base navigation first) :

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack'
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-tabs'
import { StyleSheet, Image } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import Home from '../components/Home'
import LendList from '../components/LendList'
import AddMoney from '../components/AddMoney'
import AddStuff from '../components/AddStuff'
import Settings from '../components/Settings'
import Test from '../components/Test'

function HomeScreen() {
    return(
        <Home/>
    )
}

function LendListScreen() {
    return(
        <LendList/>
    )
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator()

function App() {
    return(
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
                <Stack.Screen name="Home"
                component={Home} 
                options={{ title: "Home Page"}}
                />
                <Stack.Screen name="LendList" 
                component={LendList}
                options={{ title: 'Liste' }}
                />
                <Stack.Screen name="AddMoney"
                component={AddMoney} 
                options={{ title: "Ajout Money"}}
                />
                <Stack.Screen name="AddStuff"
                component={AddStuff} 
                options={{ title: "Ajout Stuff"}}
                />
                <Stack.Screen name="Settings"
                component={Settings} 
                options={{ title: "Settings"}}
                />
                <Stack.Screen name="Test"
                component={Test} 
                options={{ title: "Test"}}
                />
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    )
}

export default App
```

And then come each of my pages (coded with classes), and here is one example, Home.js (I removed all the Style part to shorten the code displayed here) :

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, Image, View, Button, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import Moment from 'react-moment'
import { CommonActions } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native'

class Home extends React.Component {

    static navigationOptions = () => {

        return {
            headerRight: () => <TouchableOpacity style={styles.settings_touchable_headerrightbutton}
                            onPress={() => this.goToSettings()}>
                            <Image style={styles.settings_image}
                            source={require('../assets/ic_settings.png')} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
        }
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this._goToSettings = this._goToSettings.bind(this)
    }

    _updateNavigationParams() {
        navigation.setParams({
          goToSettings: this._goToSettings
        })
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        console.log("navigation")
        this._updateNavigationParams()

    }

    _checkMoneyDetails(navigation){
        navigation.navigate('LendList', {type: 'Money'})
    }

    _checkStuffDetails(navigation){
        navigation.navigate('LendList', {type: 'Stuff'})
    }

    _checkPeopleDetails(navigation){
        navigation.navigate('LendList', {type: 'People'})
    }

    _goToSettings = () => {
        navigation.navigate('Settings')
    }

    render(){
        const date = new Date();
        const { navigation } = this.props;

        return(
            <View style={styles.main_container}>
                <View style={styles.header_view}>
                    <Text style={styles.header_text}>GiViToMe</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.header_text}>Nous sommes le :{' '}
                    {/* TODO: Penser à gérer ensuite les formats de date étrangers */}
                        <Moment element={Text} format="DD/MM/YYYY" date={date}/>
                    </Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.lend_view}>
                    <Text style={styles.title_lend_text}>Vos prêts :</Text>
                    <View style={styles.money_stuff_view}>
                        <View style={styles.money_view}>
                            <View style={styles.money_data_view}>
                                <Image source={require('../assets/ic_money.png')} style={styles.home_img} />
                                <Text>XXX $</Text>
                            </View>
                            <Button title='Money' onPress={() => {this._checkMoneyDetails(navigation)}}/>
                        </View>
                        <View style={styles.stuff_view}>
                            <View style={styles.stuff_data_view}>
                                <Image source={require('../assets/ic_box.png')} style={styles.home_img} />
                                <Text>XXX objets</Text>
                            </View>
                            <Button title='Stuff' onPress={() => {this._checkStuffDetails(navigation)}}/>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.people_view}>
                        <View style={styles.people_data_view}>
                            <Image source={require('../assets/ic_people.png')} style={styles.home_img} />
                            <Text>XXX people</Text>
                        </View>
                        <Button title='People' onPress={() => {this._checkPeopleDetails(navigation)}}/>
                    </View>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.footer_view}>
                    <Text style={styles.text_footer_view}>a.vescera inc.</Text>
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }    
}

export default Home
```

My problem is that, per the online documentation, I saw that to use "navigation" or "route" within a class, I should use the `const navigation = { this.props }` after the `render()` function.

This problem is that, to use one specific function within the header, I have to bind it after the `componentDidMount()` function, but the value present under `render()` is not yet known.

How could I solve this ? (sure that in the given example, having all the code in the navigation part allow to use `navigation` and `route` easily but you understand that I have to split my code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, so each time the same, I try many days solving my problem, and when I finally decide to post on stack, I find a solution :).

So, if there's some performance issue or other you may see by looking at my code, do not hesitate to correct me. I just found that this solution solved my problem.

So within my Navigation.js file, I just passed the navigation and route objects to make them usable thanks to the props into my classes, like this :

```
function App() {
    return(
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
                <Stack.Screen name="Home"
                component={Home} 
                options={({route, navigation}) => (
                    {headerTitle: 'Home Page', 
                    route: {route}, 
                    navigation: {navigation}}
                )}
                />
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigatorContainer>
)}
```

then within my classes I just call to `this.props.navigation` or `this.props.route` and gather form these objects what I need.

Other thing is that, for those who would use this code to build something similar, I also had to change the way I display the header button.
I do not use the `static navigationOptions = () => {}` anymore. I just add directly the `navigation.setOptions` piece of code within the `ComponentDidMount` function like this:

```
navigation.setOptions({
            headerRight: () => <TouchableOpacity style={styles.settings_touchable_headerrightbutton}
                            onPress={() => route.params.goToSettings()}>
                            <Image style={styles.settings_image}
                            source={require('../assets/ic_settings.png')} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
        })
```

I have to do it this way since I'm using a function declared in my class, so I have to bind it in the constructor like this `this._goToSettings = this._goToSettings.bind(this)` and then add it to the `navigation.setParams` function.

Comment: I did not understand a thing you did! I have the same case, I have Navigation stack location in navigation.js, I have home_bar function in a separate file where I return three screens including Home screen. Now, I want to add the button in Home header but it doesn't work if i add the code for the button in Home class. It works if I do it in home_bar function but I cant really pass any parameters to that button in that file

Comment: If you want, please add your code (maybe create a ticket and paste the link here) so I could have a look. It's been a year now, so maybe some things have changed and what worked yesterday don't work anymore today.

Answer (score 0):

When `navigation.setOptions` code is written inside `componentDidMount` add `this.props` before `navigation` and `route` keyword. Below is the code snippet that worked for me.

```
this.props.navigation.setOptions({
            headerRight: () => <TouchableOpacity style={styles.settings_touchable_headerrightbutton}
                            onPress={() => this.props.route.params.goToSettings()}>
                            <Image style={styles.settings_image}
                            source={require('../assets/ic_settings.png')} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
        })
```